# Get url & change it on click

Tags: javascript, url

I want to get the current page url (http://example.com/en-user/?1234) and on button click change "en-user" with "hi-user" and go to that page, so the url should be like "http://example.com/hi-user/?1234". Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try something on your own

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple... Set up a click event handler on the button, get the location, adjust the string, set the URL.

```js
// Get button reference
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Set up click event handler
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get current URL
  var url = window.location.href;

  console.log(url);

  // Change a portion of the string
  // Obviously, change the values to suit your needs.
  url = url.replace(".net", ".com");

  console.log(url);

  // Navigate to new URL
  window.location.href = url;

});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Change URL</button>
```